Can I squeeze rock wool insulation into a smaller cavity space?
I have a stud wall that's 45mm. Can I squeeze in rockwool batts that are 50mm thick?

This depends on what you are compressing against. Comfortboard is fairly dense. If both sides of the wall are plywood, no problem. If one or both sides are drywall, you'll risk bowing or popping the anchors.
If you want to ensure a flat appearance, mount the board in your wall cavity and trim the excess with a wood saw across the face using the studs as a guide.
You can also shim the wall out enough to compensate for the difference.

This, I wondered about the compressibility of the board the OP mentioned.

Usually with insulation the more, the merrier.  Adding 3/16/5mm shims will not hurt.  Depending on the room size, adding 50mm wood to the outside studs might be nice to your pocket book in the future.

5mm is barely over 3/16". Not a significant amount in the context of insulation.
There is very little compression to degrade the insulation factor.
You should be fine.
